# Yii2. Widgets and Actions

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am in the process of learning Yii2 more in depth, so I was wondering if it is possible for a widget to have something similar to actions in a controller?

In example:

```
class WTest extends Widget {

    public ...;

    public function init() {
      ...
    }

    public function run() {
        Pjax::begin();
        echo "<a href='".Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl("test/add")."'>Add test</a>";
        Pjax::end();
    }

    public function addThing() {
      echo "hola"
    }
}
```

Then in a controller do:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
  public function actionAdd() {
    $wObj = new WTest;
    return $wObj->addThing();
  }
}
```

The issues with this way is that I loose all the parameters set when calling the widget in the form, since I am calling "new WTest", it is a new instance. I have tried using a static method too, but similar issue, any ideas?

**UPDATE**
In the view, I am calling the widget like this:

```
        WTest::widget([
            'test' => 'hi'
        ]);
```

Comment: If you want to have only one instance, you should use `singleton` pattern for it.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am not sure how to apply Singleton in this case

Answer (score 2):

Update: Remove `private __contruct(), __clone()` and use yii2 dependency injection.
In class `WTest`, you should define some function and variables:

```
class WTest extends Widget
{
    /**
     * @var WTest The reference to *WTest* instance of this class
     */
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * Returns *WTest* instance of this class.
     *
     * @return WTest The *WTest* instance.
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (null === static::$instance) {
            static::$instance = new static();
            //Add more attribute and do many stuff here
        }

        return static::$instance;
    }

    //If you want set value for variable, use yii2 DI
    /** @var string $test */
    public $test;
}
```

And use in your action:

```
public function actionAdd() {
    $wObj = WTest::getInstance();
    return $wObj->addThing();
}
```

Use in views:

```
WTest::widget([
    'test' => 'value',
]);
```

Hope it helpful.

More info about singleton pattern: http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/singleton.html.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time. I will give it a try and experiment with this :)

Comment: It seems it does not work: 1. clone and construct are required to be public due methods from super classes. 2. When I call widget from view I pass it parameters, how can I keep them using Singleton?

Comment: I update my answer, if you want to inject value to variables, you dont need singleton. Yii2 designed with dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from ThanhPV was not completely right but it guide me to the correct direction by using Dependency Injection :)